# Excel VBA - For loop .Find cell with value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, find

I am struggling to write an effective macro that will find a cell with error in column, then replace that cell with value of the first non-empty cell without error below it (there might be consecutive error cells) then loop for 12 columns.

The code I have below replaces each of the error cells in all 12 columns, but not in a consistent manner: some cells will indeed be filled by the next cell below that contains a number, but some cells end up with value of the second next cell below that contains a number. I can't tell where the problem in my code is.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ClearError()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkSheet1").Activate

    Dim c, x, z As Integer
    Dim y As Long

    For z = 3 To 14 Step 1   ' Start with column 'C' and do for total of 12 columns
    x = 999

        For c = 1 To x Step 1
            If IsError(Cells(c, z)) Then
               Cells(c, z) = Range(Cells(1, z), Cells(x, z)).Find(y, _
                             After:=Cells(c, z), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Value
            End If
        Next c   
    Next z

End Sub
```

If you could offer any insight or advice, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time! Ante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reversing your loop.

```
For c = x to 1 Step -1
    If IsError(Cells(c, z)) Then
           Cells(c, z) = Cells(c + 1, z)
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, bp_. I'm afraid the results are the same after the change.

Comment: Thank you, bp_. That did the trick perfectly. If you don't mind me picking your brain a bit, do you have any idea why my code didn't yield consistent results?

Comment: It doesn't look like you set the .find function appropriately.  What is your variable 'y'?

Comment: I am still very fresh with VBA - 'y' was supposed to be any number as the "What" parameter for the .find function. I couldn't quite figure out what else to put there and this seemed to be working.

Comment: Since you did not declare y as anything (ie. y=15), it defaulted to 0.  So the find function was looking for 0.

Comment: Oh, I see. What should have I declared it as so that the function would look for any number, not just 15, for instance?

Comment: [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx)  The find function doesn't really work like that.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and help, bp_.